# Linker Command Failed, Duplicate Symbol

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I have a simple project with three files. Main.cpp, CountTriangles.cpp, and CountTriangles.hpp. When I try to build/run, I get "Linker command failed with exit code 1" and, in the log, I find "ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64".

main.cpp:

```
#include "CountTriangles.cpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

CountTriangles.cpp:

```
#include "CountTriangles.hpp"
using namespace std;

int TriangleCount::count(int N){
    int helper = 1;
    return helper;
}
```

CountTriangles.hpp:

```
#ifndef CountTriangles_hpp
#define CountTriangles_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class TriangleCount{
    public:
        int count(int N);
};

#endif /* CountTriangles_hpp */
```

Comment: You `#include` the *source* file, not the header file. Don't do that.

Comment: In main you include `#include "CountTriangles.cpp"` instead of the .hpp file.

Comment: And for future questions, please read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should really *copy-paste* the error output. In full, complete, and with any possible informational notes that might exist.

Comment: OK, I read the page you referenced and, as a result, reduced the code to a minimum. I'm confused about what you said about the error output. I thought I included what was necessary while cutting out everything that's specific to my machine and file structures. What else should I have included?

Answer (score 1):

In `main.cpp` you include `#include "CountTriangles.cpp"` but you should be in including the header `CountTriangles.hpp`

Since the definition of `TriangleCount::count(int N)` is then being compiled twice, redefined, you get the resulting duplicate symbol error.